# Need some help on my Four Feature file How to Run Multiple Feature File?

Tags: junit, cucumber, feature-file

Here's my Code

```
@CucumberOptions(       
    features = "src/testresources",
    glue={"Nismo.live.stepsdefinition"},
    tags = {"@CreateNewCourse.Feature,@CreateNewUserAndEnrolledToaCourse.Feature,@LoginLockout.Feature,@LoginOnNismo.Feature,@StudentCarryoverAttempresults.Feature"}           
)

public class CucumberRunnerNismo {
}
```

Error:

> None of the features at [src/testresources] matched the filters:
>   [@CreateNewCourse.Feature,@CreateNewUserAndEnrolledToaCourse.Feature,@LoginLockout.Feature,@LoginOnNismo.Feature,@StudentCarryoverAttempresults.Feature]
>
> 0 Scenarios 0 Steps 0m0.000s

Comment: i also tried this code but no avail @CucumberOptions(
 
 //plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/html-report/","json:target/cucumber-json-"+"report.json"},
  features = "src/testresources",
  glue={"Nismo.live.stepsdefinition"},
  tags = {"@CreateNewCourse,@CreateNewUserAndEnrolledToaCourse,@LoginLockout,@LoginOnNismo,@StudentCarryoverAttempresults"}   
    
 )


public class CucumberRunnerNismo {


}

Comment: What happens when you remove all the tag filters?

Comment: Refer to this answer => [Run Multiple Files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45093925/11617138)

Answer (score 0):

features = "src/testresources", => does this need to be features = "src/test/resources"?
And/or remove the tags like Grasshopper suggested.